# Get ip add and hostname of machines using script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, powershell

I would like to get ip add and hostname of machines when i start them. i already installed 3 virtual machine on vmware with dynamic ip .
its form: 
 xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.    hostname.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the documentation of the vmware product you are using.

Comment: what os are you running on the virtual machines?  Would it be ok to see the ip on the machines, or do you want the script on the host machine, not the virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try get Ipdata function:

```
Function Get-IPData {
#this function assumes admin credentials
[cmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [Alias("name")]
    [string[]]$computername=$env:computername
)

Process {
    ForEach ($computer in $computername) {
        Write-Verbose "Querying $($computer.ToUpper())"
        Try 
        {
        #get NICS that are IP and DHCP enabled
         Get-WMIObject -Class win32_networkadapterconfiguration -computername $Computer `
        -Filter "IPEnabled='TRUE' AND DHCPEnabled='TRUE'" -ErrorAction "Stop" | 
        Select Description,DNSHostname,
        @{Name="IPAddress";Expression={$_.IPAddress[0]}},
        @{Name="SubnetMask";Expression={$_.IPSubnet[0]}},
        @{Name="DefaultGateway";Expression={$_.DefaultIPGateway[0]}},DNSDomain,
        @{Name="PrimaryDNS";Expression={$_.DNSServerSearchOrder[0]}},DHCPServer,
        @{Name="DHCPLease";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.DHCPLeaseObtained)}},
        @{Name="DHCPExpires";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.DHCPLeaseExpires)}},
        @{Name="DHCPTimeToLive";Expression={ $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.DHCPLeaseExpires) - (Get-Date)}},
        MACAddress,
        @{Name="Speed";Expression={
        #use an Associators Of query to get the NIC
          $nic=Get-WmiObject -query "associators of {Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Index=$($_.index)}" -computername $computer
          $nic.Speed
          }}
    } #close Try
    Catch
        {
            Write-Warning "Failed to retrieve IP configuration from $($computer.ToUpper())"
            Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message

        } #close Catch
    } #close ForEach
 } #close Process
} #end function
```